# How can i sort subcategories in magento by their name?

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento.
I want to sort my subcategories list by name  how can i do it? 
please tell me step by step.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are asking to sort sub-category list which comes in top menu. For doing this, follow these simple step:

1. Login to admin.
2. Go to Catalog->Manage Categories
3. Then, drag and drop subcategory according to your required position.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Initialy category list is sorted but when i select any category then subcategories of that particular category is not sorted

Comment: same way you can drag and set subcategory position from backend.